# Vertical centering with translateY does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a text of variable length inside a container with fixed height. I thought I've found a solution with an absolute positioned wrapper container, using

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

on the text to be centered. It works fine in Firefox and IE, but does not work in Chrome:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9uathmvh/7/

Does anyone know why? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because anchor tag is not a block element.

I removed the position rules in `.container` and `.link` classes and just set the anchor element height of `100%` in order to fill its container.

In my opinion, it would be better to vertically center the whole `a.link` rather than only its content, but I don't know your exactly needs, so I left it like you asked it.

Please take a look in the snippet below:

```css
.container {
  height: 42px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.link {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
} 

.center {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="link">
    <div class="center">
      Centered Text in one line
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a class="link">
    <div class="center">
      Centered Text, more than one line but still centered
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```